# What Sci-Fi novel is about aliens who consider it simply convenient to exterminate the human race?

Tags: story-identification, novel, alien-invasion

I don't remember the title/author of a Sci-Fi novel, where the author demonstrated that in case of an encounter with a more advanced alien life form, they would consider most convenient for them to exterminate the human race instead of every other alternative...

Comment: I attempted to improve the title to make it more of a question.  If it's not to your liking, feel free to roll the change back or improve it further.

Comment: Stories about aliens exterminating humans (or vice versa, for that matter) are very common. There are many that would fit your description. You need to give more details: what other plot elements do you remember? Were there other characters? How much did aliens debate what to do? What resistance did humans oppose? Did the aliens visit Earth or did humans visit the aliens? etc. Also meta-elements: when did you read it, was it new at the time, do you remember anything about the cover image, …?

Comment: Surely not the Vogons? :)

Comment: @Mark: thank you, English is just my third language ;)

Comment: @Gilles: You're right, but what I've written was all I remember. :(
@muntoo: reading them some poetry first... :)

Comment: "To Serve Man" (short story and I think a Twilight Zone episode.)

Comment: The classic Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy? Earth was in the way of building some sort of interstellar highway so got destroyed.

Comment: "To Serve Man" was not about extermination or convenience.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think this might be Killing Star by Charles Pellegrino and George Zebrowski. After aliens destroy the Earth with relativistic bombs they explain to the last human that because all civilizations are potentially dangerous, and there's really nothing to lose by exterminating them before they get too strong, it was the logical choice.

Answer (score 6):

Reminds me of The Screwfly Solution by James Tiptree, Jr - a short story in Warm Worlds and Otherwise. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Screwfly_Solution

Comment: A great story! although there is a difference between convenience and real-estate;)

Answer (score 5):

Sounds a bit like "Protector" by Larry Niven.

Comment: Except that that wasn't the relationship between Pak and humans.  Nobody was trying to exterminate the species.

Comment: That's why I said "sounds a bit like...".  The book does talk about how the protectors consider exterminating other sentient species the most prudent course of action.

Comment: That's exactly what I remember ... many years ago I read about a sci-fi novel containing some sort of philosophical demonstration that exterminating the other sentient species was the best move. But I wasn't able to find it and then I forgot the author and the title...

Answer (score 5):

In Stephen Baxter's Xeelee sequence, the Xeelee are fighting a dark energy enemy far superior beyond human comprehension and are simply annoyed that the humans keep pestering them with attacks in an attempt to bring
"peace" to the universe by subjugating all other races. The Xeelee are far
superior to all other races including humans, and are forced by humans, who
insist on attacking them while they are busy trying to save the universe from
the dark energy photino birds, to simply and effortlessly wipe out the human
race, though they save a small sample community of humans on an artificial
world with an artificial sun so they can continue to exist in a harmless
fashion; see *Ring* and *Vacuum Diagrams* by Stephen Baxter.

Answer (score 5):

There's *The Genocides* by Thomas M. Disch.  Humanity isn't even noticed in that, or *The Forge of God* by Greg Bear, where we get annihilated just to be on the safe side.